# Error While Adding Dynamic Framework inside a Project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

We have created a framework and it works fine without any error but when i create a fat framework and add that framework into the other project i get this type of error

'''

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for SafexPay.SafexPay

Undefined symbol: static SafexPay.SafexPay.sharedInstance.getter : SafexPay.SafexPay

Undefined symbol: dispatch thunk of SafexPay.SafexPay.configure(MerchantId: Swift.String, key: Swift.String, environment: Swift.String) -> ()

Undefined symbol: dispatch thunk of SafexPay.SafexPay.showPaymentGateway(on: __C.UIViewController, price: Swift.String, orderId: Swift.String, currency: Swift.String, txnType: Swift.String, channel: Swift.String, countryCode: Swift.String, aggregator: Swift.String, successUrl: Swift.String, failureUrl: Swift.String) -> ()

'''

Can Anyone Please Help me out to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, finally, I found it is due to [Swift Library Evolution](https://www.swift.org/blog/library-evolution/).

When we build fat framework, we pass `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES` to xcodebuild, but when you add it to the project, the dependency written by swift didn't.

So, just add `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES` to BUILDSETTINGS solve this error.

Cocoapods example:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
  end
end
```